# How to create a textInput for the expiration date of a credit card with this format: MM/YY in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, textinput

I wish to create a textInput for the expiration date of a credit card with this format: MM/YY. I'm programming with React Native and TypeScript, I installed react-native-masked-text library.

My doubt is how to put the month and the year in a single variable, in the database and in another file I have declared the month and the year separately, I have it like this:

```
const [cardMM, setcardMM]...
const [cardYY, setcardYY]...


   <TextInputMask
     type='custom'
     value={}
     options={{ mask: 'MM/YY' }}
     keyboardType='numeric'
     style={{ color: 'white', top: 35 }}
     onChangeText={() => ()}

   />
```

I don't know how the value and the onChangeText would go because I have the month and the year separately.

Comment: Are you asking how to split "02/24" into "02" and "24"?

Comment: mm the opposite, I want the textInput to be 02/24, I don't know how to put the value and the OnchangeText because I already have the variables declared
[cardMM, setcardMM]
[cardYY, setcardYY]

Comment: Just use a single state variable and split it when the form is submitted (thought my first comment made this obvious, sorry)